# Martians on Everest

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find a short story about Martians being found living on the peak of Mount Everest. The story precedes the first climb of Everest (1953) and had the protagonist reach the summit in a helicopter or plane, rather than by climbing. I read it in an anthology of short stories sometime in the 80s. The Martians were there because the low atmospheric pressure and cold temperatures mimicked Martian conditions, but I don't recall if they had a mission to complete.

Comment: If it is indeed *Everest*, then you should now that while the story was written a month or so before the first person reached the peak of Everest, it wasn't published until about seven months after the peak was reached.  The story predicted that no one would ever climb Everest seven months after it had already been done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [*Everest*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everest_(short_story)) by Isaac Asimov.

> The story concerns a mountain climber named James Abram Robbons who is the first man to reach the summit of Mount Everest, after having been dropped there by airplane. Robbons is picked up again two weeks later, and he reports that the summit of Everest is the location of a Martian outpost, and that the yeti are actually Martians.

Comment: In the Cthulhu Mythos aliens from another dimension who have coloized the planet Yuggoth in the outer edge of the solar system have outposts on Earth, usually on the peaks of mountains.  They were responsible for reports of Yeti or Mi-go in Tibet. https://lovecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Mi-go  So the idea of aliens on Everest goes back as far as Lovecraft's  "The Whisperer in Darkness" - it was implied that they were respnsible for the dissappearance of Mallory and Irvine..